# ayuda con VistaParcial de C# y eventos de jquery

Tags: javascript, c#

buen dia amigos resulta que tengo la siguiente problematica.

1. en un div de nombre **actionContainer** cargo el resultado de una vista parcial de c# para ello uso el siguiente codigo

```html
 <a href="#" class="btnEditar" data-id="@item.MtoOfertaId" title="Editar Información"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Editar</a>
```

ahora en mi script es el siguiente.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.btnEditar', function () {        
    $.ajax({
        url: _urlBase + 'Ofertas/Edit',
        data: { id: $(this).attr('data-id') },
        beforeSend: function (objeto) {
            openLoad();
        }
    })
    .done(function (response) {
       // $('#IndexBuscar').hide();            
        $("#actionContainer").html(response);
        focusAction();
        closeLoad();
    })
    .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        swal('!Error', 'Ocurrio un error intente nuevamente', 'error');
    });


});
```

el cual me carga la vistaparcial en el div hasta aqui no tengo problemas, el problema empieza cuando en la vista parcial que se cargo tiene unos eventos jquery que no se ejecutan, la vista parcial que me carga tiene el sigueinte codigo

```
    @model WebDBT.Models.NewOfertaView

    <script src="~/Scripts/WebScript/MtoOferta.js"></script>
    <div class="box">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
         <h3 class="box-title">Edición Oferta Técnico-Económica</h3>
         <div class="box-tools pull-right">         
         </div>
     </div>

    <div class="box-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "EditOferta", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            //HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false; opcion que tengo desactivar para que haga la validacion con jqueryvalidate
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MtoOfertaId, new { @id = "MtoOfertaId" });
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MtoUsuarioId, new { @id = "MtoUsuarioId" });


            <div id="CapturaOfertas" class="form-input">

                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MtoProcedimientoId, "Procedimiento*", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("MtoProcedimientoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @onchange = "GetPartidas(this.value)" })
                        <span class="error">Requerido</span>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MtoProcedimientoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MtoProveedorId, "Licitante*", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("MtoProveedorId")
                        <span class="error">Requerido</span>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MtoProveedorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "ErrorProveedor" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MtoRequerimientoId, "Partida/Clave *", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("MtoRequerimientoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @onchange = "GetDetallePartida(this.value)" })
                        <span class="error">Requerido</span>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MtoRequerimientoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="detallePartida">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gpo, "Gpo *", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gpo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center", id = "Gpo", name = "Gpo" } })
                            <span class="error">Requerido</span>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gpo, "", new { @class = "text-danger required" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gen, "Gen *", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center", id = "Gen", name = "Gen" } })
                            <span class="error">Requerido</span>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gen, "", new { @class = "text-danger required" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Esp, "Esp *", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Esp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center" } })
                            <span class="error">Requerido</span>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Esp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dif, "Dif *", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dif, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center" } })
                            <span class="error">Requerido</span>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dif, "", 
 new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Var, "* Var", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Var, new { 
 htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center" } })
                            <span class="error">Requerido</span>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Var, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>P.M.R.</label>
                            <input type="text" id="pmr" class="text-center" 
 disabled="disabled" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Máximo Requerido</label>
                            <input type="text" id="MaxReq" class="text-center" 
 disabled="disabled" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>


                <!--Precio y cantidades ofertados-->
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrecioOfertado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="form-group inputWithIcon">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrecioOfertado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center Precios" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrecioOfertado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg fa-lw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descuento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="form-group inputWithIcon">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descuento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center Precios" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descuento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-lg fa-lw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaximoOfertado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="form-group inputWithIcon">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaximoOfertado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center Cantidad" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaximoOfertado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <i class="fa fa-th fa-lg fa-lw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinimoOfertado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="form-group inputWithIcon">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MinimoOfertado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center Cantidad" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinimoOfertado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <i class="fa fa-th fa-lg fa-lw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MontoPartida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="form-group inputWithIcon">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MontoPartida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-center Precios" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MontoPartida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg fa-lw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


                @*========================================================================
                    TABLA PARA AGREGAR LAS MARCAS OFERTADAS POR EL PROVEEDOR
                    ========================================================================*@
                <div class="details">

                    <table id="tblMarcasTemp" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable table-hover" role="grid">
                        <thead>

                            <tr class="warning">
                                <th class="text-center">Denominación</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Registro Sanitario</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Titular Registro</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Procedencia</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Fabricante</th>
                                <th class="col-lg-1">
                                    <button type="button" id="addMarcaTabla" name="addMarcaTabla" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            @if (Model.DetalleOferta != null)
                            {
                                for (var i = 0; i < Model.DetalleOferta.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                    <tr class="itemMarcasAgregadas">
                                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.DetalleOferta[i].Marca, new { @class = "denominacion" })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.DetalleOferta[i].RegistroSanitario, new { @class = "registroSanitario" })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.DetalleOferta[i].TitularRegistro, new { @class = "rfcTitular searchInput" })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.DetalleOferta[i].Origen, new { @class = "procedencia" })</td>
                                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.DetalleOferta[i].Fabricante, new { @class = "fabricante searchInput" })</td>


                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" name="removeMarcaTemp" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm removeMarcaTemp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>


            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer text-right">

        <button class="btn-style-two btnCancelEdit" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            Cancelar
        </button>
        @*<a href="#" id="submitPropuesta" type="button" class="btn-style-one"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp;Guardar</a>*@
        <!--<button class="btn-style-one BtnUpdate" type="submit"><i class="fa  fa-check"></i> Guardar</button>-->
        <button id="BtnUpdate" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fac-check"></i>&nbsp;Guardar</button>
        @*<a href="#" id="BtnUpdate" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="padding:10px 20px"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp;Guardar Cambios</a>*@

    </div>
</div>

<style>
    span.error {
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
        color: red;
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    tr.error {
        background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.35);
    }

    .Resaltar {
        border-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

y por ejemplo no funciona el boton de agregar, el boton de guardar y el script completo es el siguiente.

```
    $('body').on('click', '#BtnUpdate', function () {       

        if (ValEcoTec()) {
            var NewOferta = {
                MtoOfertaId: $('#MtoOfertaId').val(),
                MaximoOfertado: accounting.toFixed($('#MaximoOfertado').val())
            };
            /*var NewOferta = {
                MtoOfertaId: $("#MtoOfertaId").val(),
                Partida: $("#MtoRequerimientoId").val(),
                Gpo: $("#Gpo").val(),
                Gen: $("#Gen").val(),
                Esp: $("#Esp").val(),
                Dif: $("#Dif").val(),
                Var: $("#Var").val(),
                PrecioOfertado: $('#PrecioOfertado').val(),
                Descuento: $('#Descuento').val(),
                MaximoOfertado: $('#MaximoOfertado').val(),
                MinimoOfertado: 
 $('#MinimoOfertado').val(),//$.number($('#MinimoOfertado').val(),true),
                MontoPartida: $('#MontoPartida').val(),
                MtoProcedimientoId: $('#MtoProcedimientoId').val(),
                MtoUsuarioId: $('#MtoUsuarioId').val(),
                MtoRequerimientoId: $('#MtoRequerimientoId').val(),
                MtoProveedorId: $('#MtoProveedorId').val(),
                DetalleOfertasTemp: list
            }*/

            console.log(NewOferta);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: _urlBase + "Ofertas/Edit/",
                contenType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
                data: { view: NewOferta, "__RequestVerificationToken": 
 $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },
                datatype: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (objeto) {
                    openLoad();
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {

                        closeLoad();

                        swal('Hecho', 'Los Datos proporcionados se guardaron satisfacctoriamente', 'success');

                        //limpio los campos
                        limpiar(false);

                        //limpio el arreglo de marcas
                        list = [];

                        //limpio la tabla de marcas
                        $('#tblMarcasTemp tbody').empty();

                    }
                    else {
                        var IsValid = false;
                        swal('Oops!', 'ocurrio un error durante el guardado', 'error');
                        $('#submit').html('Guardar Propuesta');
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    $('#submit').html('Guardar Propuesta');
                    var IsValid = false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

podrian echarme una mano de porque no se ejecuta los comandos.

no omito mencionar el que script lo cargo en la pagina principal

Comment: Trata poniendo los javascript y estilos en tu página principal en lugar de la vista parcial.

Comment: ya hice eso, pero aun asi no funciona